# Modify global struct variable in C

Tags: c

Using global variable, the `printf` doesn't return a valid value.
I tried this code with no success:

```
struct test {
   char *a;
   char *b;
}    
struct test test_main = {};
int modif_value(char *val) {
   test_main.a = val;
}
int main () {
   modif_value("1");
   printf ("value after modif is %s \n", test_main.a);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I made changes necessary for this to properly compile (added ';' after struct closing brace, changed return type of modif_value from int to void) and it works as expected.

Do you see compile errors or warnings?

If it compiles, what output do you see?

Answer (score 1):

well ... this is the right code ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct test {
char *a;
char *b;
};

struct test test_main;
void modif_value(char *val) {
test_main.a = val;
}
int main () {
char c='1';
modif_value(&c);
printf ("value after modif is %s \n", test_main.a);
return 0;
}
```

1. don't forget ... after struct definition you should use (;)
2. modif_value doesn't return anything so write VOID in the prototype
3. you should pass an address to modif_value function ! not the character !

Comment: Why you prefer snippet, it's for JavaScript/HTML/CSS.

Comment: The `%s` format requires a null-terminated string. This code tries to print the address of `c`, which is not a null-terminated string - so it's worse than OP's code.